# Setting display to `revert` works in Firefox, but not in other browseres

Tags: javascript, css

No much to say, my script works fine in Firefox but its not in Chrome or IE or Opera

```
var ids = ['id1','id2'];
function myfunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {    
        var x = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "revert";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you execute your function?

Comment: `getElementById` works in all browsers, that's not the problem. The problem here is `revert`, that will work only on Firefox (and Safari as well).

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert#Browser_compatibility for the list of browsers that support the `revert` CSS keyword.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado I tried to change it to `block` but also not working

Comment: @Mihail Minkov I tried before and after the html element, then moved to the end of the body but still not working

Comment: @sammax If you have a solution, post it as an answer.  SO doesn't follow the typical forum style of editing the original question to include an answer in it; it has a separate area for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
The element was apart of a table so, I changed `revert` to `inline-table` and it works fine. Also, as the guys recommended `revert` is not supported in chrome or IE